# Javascript : Modify object and add new index to a property

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

My object is something like:

```
let items = 
    [
        {
            "creationTimeStamp": "2022-05-31T17:04:28.000Z",
            "modifiedTimeStamp": "2022-05-31T17:04:28.000Z",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "id": "5ao",
                    "name": "Store1"
                }
            ],
            "typeId": "Lead"
        }
    ]
```

I am trying to push the following object into the `locations` property:

```
{
    "id": "9a0",
    "name": "Store2"
}
```

I have tried doing

```
items1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items1.id = "9a0";
    items1.name = "Store2";
    //9 is some static index value added
    Object.assign({9 : items1}, items[i].locations);
}
```

If I `console(Object.assign({9 : items1}, items[i].locations));` I can see 2 arrays inside it, but my items `locations` property is still the same.

My expectation is as below:

```
[
    {
        "creationTimeStamp": "2022-05-31T17:04:28.000Z",
        "modifiedTimeStamp": "2022-05-31T17:04:28.000Z",
        "locations": [
            {
                "id": "5ao",
                "name": "Store1"
            },
            {
                "id": "9a0",
                "name": "Store2"
            }
        ],
        "typeId": "Lead"
    }
]
```

I also tried to use `items[i].locations.push(item1)` but then got:

> TypeError: Cannot add property 9, object is not extensible

I also tried to assign a new array to `items[i].locations`, but then got:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'locations' of object '#'

What can I do to get the desired result?

Comment: `Object.assign` mutates the *first* argument, not the second. Swap the arguments.

Comment: @trincot
can you please explain in detail

Comment: can you use arr.push() ?

Comment: as in... items[0].locations.push({"ddd":00})

Comment: I am getting error as : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot add property 9, object is not extensible if i use push

Comment: try using "let" instead of "const"

Comment: actually it is let only, i have updated above post

Comment: What do you mean by having that `items1 = [];` ?

Comment: you can also do like this in for loop.
`items[i].locations = Object.assign({9 : items1}, items[i].locations);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to expect that the second argument given to `Object.assign` will be mutated. But it is the first argument that is mutated. That means your `.locations` is *not* mutated. Moreover, in comments you indicate that `locations` cannot be extended and that the property is read-only.

So that means you'll need a complete new object.

Some other remarks:

- Don't initialise `items1` as an array, since it is supposed to be a plain object.
- Declare a variable with `const`, `let` or `var` and avoid implicit global declaration.
- It is safer to declare the `items1` object inside the loop, so you create a new object each time and don't mutate the *same* object. For your example code it makes no difference, but it can lead to unexpected behaviour.
- As you don't need `i` for anything else than `items[i]`, and you actually need a complete new structure, use `.map` instead.

So:

```
items = items.map(item => {
    let obj = {
        id: "9a0",
        name: "Store2"
    };
    return {...item, locations: item.locations.concat(obj) };
});
```

Comment: I have tried item.locations = [...item.locations, obj]; shown above and getting error as below : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'locations' of object '#<Object>'

Comment: So you know what that means, right?

Comment: which means cannot add into locations, how this can be resolved?

Comment: It means your data structure is read-only and you cannot mutate it. So you must create a new data structure. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I always think in terms of functions, and of immutability-by-default, so my approach might look like this, with `addLocationToAll` built atop a simpler `addLocation`.  The code is fairly simple:

```js
const addLocation = (newLoc) => ({locations, ...rest}) => 
  ({...rest, locations: locations .concat (newLoc)})

const addLocationToAll = (newLoc) => (items) => 
  items .map (addLocation (newLoc))

const items = [{creationTimeStamp: "2022-05-31T17:04:28.000Z", modifiedTimeStamp: "2022-05-31T17:04:28.000Z", locations: [{id: "5ao", name: "Store1"}], typeId:"Lead"}]
const newLoc = {id: "9a0", name: "Store2"}

console .log (addLocationToAll (newLoc) (items))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score -1):

`items` is an array so it must access the first position of the array, which would be the proposed object.
With this, from the proposed object you will extract the`location` attribute and since this is an array, you use the push function to insert the new object

```js
items[0]
// ->
// {
//   creationTimeStamp: '2022-05-31T17:04:28.000Z',
//   modifiedTimeStamp: '2022-05-31T17:04:28.000Z',
//   locations: [ { id: '5ao', name: 'Store1' } ],
//   typeId: 'Lead'
// }
```

I try this:

```js
items[0].locations.push({"id": "9a0", "name": "Store2" })
```

And now:

```js
items[0]
//->
// {
//   creationTimeStamp: '2022-05-31T17:04:28.000Z',
//   modifiedTimeStamp: '2022-05-31T17:04:28.000Z',
//   locations: [ { id: '5ao', name: 'Store1' }, { id: '9a0', name: 'Store2' }],
//   typeId: 'Lead'
// }
```

Comment: You probably didn't offend anyone.  I'm guessing the downvote (now balanced with my upvote!) was because you didn't take into account the immutability concerns.  Those arose in the comments to the question and the question was later edited to include them.  One more thing is that you assumed that this was to be added only to the first item in the array; everyone else assumes it's supposed to be added to all of them.

Comment: An answer being downvoted on StackOverflow does not mean that it has offended someone, it merely means that it is not the optimal answer to the problem. They should not be taken personally.